# Local variable not found while iterating over dictionary in Pycharm debugger

Tags: python, pycharm

Hi I have the following example,

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.__dict__.__eq__(other.__dict__)


d1 = Dummy(1)
d2 = Dummy(2)
d = {d1: None, d2: None}

for k, v in d.items():
    print([w.id for w in d.keys() if w.id != k.id])
```

When I run the above in Pycharm it fails when I add a breakpoint at the for loop line but succeeds if I just let the code run to completion.

In debugger:

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
Python 3.6.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 28 2019, 02:16:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin

>>> for k, v in d.items():
        print([w.id for w in d.keys() if w.id != k.id])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

When I run without breakpoints:

```
/anaconda3/envs/example/bin/python example.py
[2]
[1]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm not sure if this is intended behavior or an environment issue.

Debugger failure image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you did that correctly? There should be no issue. It works fine on my system. Also, your error output does not look like PyCharm's debugger output. It also looks like you are using different files.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 I've added an image of the debugger failure for reference

Comment: Seems like a known issue in the debug console: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36512